# How to make the two different scrolling div elements to match and get in script?

Tags: css, html, scroll

I am developing a windows HTML5/javascript app and I finished 75% of work in it.

In the app a section contains two div elements scrolling vertically. When I scroll the divs it should match with the element in the other div and produce a result.

I have tried to make scrolling div elements to match but failed..
I put a screenshot of my app and you will understand it.

[image]

In the above screen first green box is one scrolling div and the other red one is one another. At the center comes near "+" the elements in div match and produce a result in the next rose box.

Please guide me to finish the app by providing a solution to match the elements in different div using HTML5 CSS3 slider.

Thanks in advance

My code which I am using for this app is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Uyirmei</title>
    <link href="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/css/ui-dark.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/base.js"></script>
<script src="//Microsoft.WinJS.1.0/js/ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Uyireluthu References-->
<link href="/css/uyirmei.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="/js/uyirmei.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <img src="images/uyirmei.png"  id="full-screen-background-image" />
         <div class="pic-row" style="position:absolute; left: 118px; top: 181.5px;">
            <img src="images/mei/off/01.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/02.png" style="width: 137px; height: 146px;" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/03.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/04.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/05.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/06.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/07.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/08.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/09.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/10.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/11.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/12.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/13.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/14.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/15.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/16.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/17.png" />
            <img src="images/mei/off/18.png" />
         </div>

    <div class="pic-row1" style="position:absolute; left: 491.5px; top: 201px;">
        <img src="images/uyir/off/01.png" style="width: 138px; height: 116px;" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/02.png" style="width: 158.5px; height: 137px;" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/03.png" style="width: 144px; height: 128px;" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/04.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/05.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/06.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/07.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/08.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/09.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/10.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/11.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/12.png" />
        <img src="images/uyir/off/13.png" />
    </div>
    <a href="default.html">
      <img style="position: absolute; width: 200px; height: 200px; left: -31.5px; top: -45px;" src="images/h_on.png">
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: you are trying to find out what 'item' is selected?

Comment: @avrahamcool Yes thats correct I want the two elements in the div to be selected when they come across the plus  sign and it should go into script and fetch a result

Comment: instead of using a standard browser scroll, I would implement two buttons, one to scroll up and one to scroll down, using JQuery, that way: the user can't scroll to something in the middle, and I know exactly what item is selected the whole time.

Comment: @avrahamcool but I am working on a Html5 app for windows and jquery is not supporting for it.. can I get it in pure css3/Html5/javascript.. please provide me help with a example

Comment: you can get the scrolling position in [JS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534618%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and then calculate who is the selected element if the height of the elements is well known.

Comment: You may want to look at a [slot machine demo](https://codepen.io/antibland/pen/ypagZd) I made. It uses a sprite with random starting points for each reel. After all reels have stopped, I check how far from zero each reel traveled relative to its respective starting point. From there, I can determine a win or loss.